# Upload and Crop image

Tags: php, ajax

Im looking for upload and crop image in PHP. The scenario is:

1. user choose image and upload to server
2. after uploaded, the website display the uploaded image.
3. user crop the image
4. And upload the cropped image to the server.

can you help me to implement this  ?

Comment: The short answer: no. Be more specific about what you're having trouble with.

Comment: I'm sorry, but please don't come here looking for tutorials. There's plenty of reference available online for what you're trying to do. I (and others) would rather not be used as a lazy shortcuts that replace learning through experimentation.

Comment: upss ..., I'm looking for the reference not looking for tutorial. My English is not good yet.

thanks for clarify my statement :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hai ,

**Jquery** can help you... For ref see this

http://www.downloadjavascripts.com/list/javasitezz62/Details.aspx

and
http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop-v11/

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:
http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html